# Intuitively, what is the difference between homeomorphism and diffeomorphism? Significance?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

As the title suggests, intuitively,  what is the difference between homeomorphism and diffeomorphism? Many thanks in advance. What is the significance of such a difference?

Comment: What's the difference between a continuous function and a smooth one?

Comment: Note that while the difference between a homeomorphism and a diffeomorphism is relatively easy to understand, the difference between two manifolds being homeomorph*ic* and diffeomorph*ic* is extremely subtle.  John Milnor won a Fields Medal in 1962 in part for giving the first example of a pair of smooth manifolds that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Homeomorphisms are the isomorphisms in the category of topological spaces and continuous functions. Diffeomorphisms are the isomorphisms in the category of smooth manifolds and functions that are not just continuous but also preserve the differential structure.

So, the difference is two-fold. First the objects are different, secondly (since every smooth manifold is in particular a topological spaces) the morphisms are required to preserve more structure.

Intuitively, a homeomorphism between smooth manifolds certainly need not preserve the differential structure. In fact, most homeomorphisms will complete disregard the differential structure. Just thing of mapping $S_1$ to $S_1$. This can be done homeomorphically in many ways, but demanding the tangent structure at each point to be mapped linearly bijectively as well required much more.

Comment: Sorry, what? I don't follow the "Just think of mapping $S_1$ to $S_1$. This can be done homeomorphically in many ways, but demanding the tangent structure at each point to be mapped linearly bijectively as well required much more" part. Could you elaborate a bit more on it?

Comment: @TimothyCarson do you know what a smooth manifold is? what the definition of diffeomorphism is?

Comment: In fact, there is only one differential structure in $S_1$, so any homeomorphism between $S_1$ is automatically a diffeomorphism

Comment: @TheOne no, just take any homeomorphism whose derivative at some point vanishes. If you think of the mapping as describing a walk around the circle, then just make sure the speed at some point is $0$.

Comment: @TheOne While there is only one differential structure on $S^1$, what you are saying is something like "Any homomorphism between two isomorphic groups is an isomorphism.". Homeomorphisms between $S^1$ are allowed to not be diffeomorphisms but you can always find some other diffeomorphism between them.